# How to click on a link to change src attribute of image(Javascript ONLY)

Tags: html, image

i have been trying to make a different image display when i click on a link, but i dont want to click on the link again to revert to the original image.

HTML:

```
    You should keep in mind that every little bit helps.The planet can't be saved from the 
<a href = "#" id = "magic" onclick = "f1(); return false;">click</a> 
of the mouse, but it certainly takes the initiative a step forward. 
    <br>
    <br>
    </div>
 <div id = "bulb">
    <center><img src = "C:\Users\hp\Desktop\on.gif" style = "width:380px;height:280px;position:relative;top:25px;border:2px solid black;"></center>
    </div>
```

Javascript :

```
<script>

function f1()
{
 document.getElementById("bulb").src = "C:\Users\hp\Desktop\off.gif";
}
</script>
```

pls tell me where have i gone wrong?? i have checked my code 3 times but cant find the problem.No jQuery pls as i dont know that yet.

Comment: Hey Pranav remove semi-colon on calling function in <a href = "#"></a>
<a href = "#" id = "magic" onclick = "f1()">click</a>

Comment: That didnt solve it...without return false the page now scrolls again to the top...also the src didnt change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code, To change image using Javascript.

```
function f1(){
var a = document.getElementById("bulb");
var b = a.querySelector('img').src = "off.gif";
}
```

Comment: thanx for it. But i want to know whats the mistake in my solution??